# iPhone 6 doesn't receive push notification

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send push notification to my app running on iOS 8.

I have two devices; one is iPad 2 with iOS 8 and another one is iPhone 6+.

Exactly the same app running on two devices and I'm using the same php script to send push notification.

I'm using following objective c code to allow push notification.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                      categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Following is the php script to send push notification

```
function sendpush($deviceToken, $message, $test = false){
    // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = '';
    $pem = dirname(__FILE__) . '/ck-pushtest.pem';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        $test ? 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195' : 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Opening SSL Connection to Push Gateway Failed." . PHP_EOL);

    // Create the payload body
    $data['aps'] = array(
        'content-available' => 1,
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default',
        'badge' => 1,
        );
    $data['push_type'] = 'link';
    $data['link'] = 'http://google.com';

    $payload = json_encode($data);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if ($result) echo '******************Success********************';
    else '******************Failed*****************************';

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
}
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = $_REQUEST['deviceToken'];
$message = 'Hi, this is a test message!';
$test = 1;

sendPush($deviceToken, $message, $test);
```

---

Problem is app running on iPad 2 (iOS 8) receives push notification, but iPhone 6+ doesn't.

What would be the issue?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: The way you authorize your app to display notifications changed in iOS 8. I'm betting that your iPad had your app installed when it was on iOS 7, and then you upgraded the iPad. The notification preferences would be remembered on that device. However, your iPhone 6 will have always had iOS 8, and probably never asked to display push notifications because the API is different. Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I have a very similar problem except in my case the identical app receives on iPhone 5 iOS 8 but not on iPad air or iPad mini. All three were installed with new app tonight so not related to previous comment. All three are using same wifi, so it's not 3G vs. wifi related.

Comment: @adeltahir, How did you fixed this issue?

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the new iPhone6 to your Development Provisioning Profile? Then download and install the profile again. This solved it for me.

Comment: If the device was not added in provision profile, how can he install build but not able to receive push notification,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could be it but I had strange issues receiving notifications also and then I read the following from the Apple documentation:

*The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a silent notification. 
For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary*

I noticed your aps dictionary had all 3 (alert sound and badge in it)
The docs went on to say that apple may not deliver the message if this is the case.

Removing those worked for me.

Thanks
Wayne