# iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Can Not Receive Remote Push Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-6, xcode-6.2

I have a really strange problem with my app on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus (iOS 8.2). I've followed and read almost everything (I Think!) that I found on the web to figure this out, but still it doesn't work. I've tested the app on iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1), 4s (iOS 7.1), 5s (iOS 8.1) and iPad Mini (iOS 8.2) and they all can receive the push notifications on from the app. My XCode version is 6.2 and the iPhone 6 devices (iOS 8.2) are detected as ineligible devices on it. So I can't even run the app right from XCode.

I'm using php script to push the notifications. When the app first run on iPhone 6, it showed up a pop up alert asking for the push notification permission. On the device's settings, the app is there on the notifications settings. I've tried revoking the apns certificate and creating a new one, re-generating the .pem files, reseting the device contents and settings, uninstall and install the app. None of these ever worked and I am already pulling my hair out. I even asked the Apple technical support for this but their answer is really just blah. I've tried downloading an app from the app store that has push notifications feature. And somewhat the device can receive push notifications from that app. So, is there anything that I am missing here? Can someone help me in this?

As suggested, here's my code for registering the notifications. I called the method "registerForRemoteNotification" from inside "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" :

```
    - (void)registerForRemoteNotification
   {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        NSLog(@"system version >= 8.0");
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"system version < 8.0");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    NSLog(@"Registering for remote notification");
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
     NSLog(@"did register remote notification with device token");
    NSString *newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"Device token: %@",newToken);
    DataManager *sharedData = [DataManager sharedInstance];
    sharedData.deviceToken = newToken;
    [self requestProfileWithDeviceToken:newToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get device token, error: %@", error);
    [self requestProfileWithDeviceToken:@""];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Receive push notification: %@",userInfo);
    [self processPushNotification:userInfo];
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Please add some code of how you register for remote notification. Just a heads up... it has changed in iOS8

Comment: Well, if the problem is in my code, I think I would've figured it out because on other posts around here, there's always at least one person coming up with the same answer. And if you read it in my description, the iPad Mini with iOS 8.2 in it is able to receive the push notifications. But I will post it up just in case. Thank you.

Comment: @tyegah123 how you traced & fixed the issue? Thank You

Comment: @Yogesh.Lolusare.Apple I haven't fixed this and still have no clue in what's causing the issue. The apple support guy was saying there's no difference between iPhone 6 and the other iPhone devices for the push notifications thingy, but well, this strange thing is happening to me and I suppose it's the same to you too.

Comment: @Tyegah123 Yes i am facing same issue. I have implemented, tested & deployed push notification but my client is having iPhone 6 device & this strange thing happening, on rest other devices everything working according to plan. Will update you if i meet with reason behind this or solution. Also one thing the device token is received for that device. Thank You

Comment: @Yogesh.Lolusare.Apple Well, hopefully then one of us will be able to fix this soon. On my side, I can also get the device token too on iPhone 6.

Comment: @Tyegeh i found this.. might be helpful ................................................The way you authorize your app to display notifications changed in iOS 8. I'm betting that your iPad had your app installed when it was on iOS 7, and then you upgraded the iPad. The notification preferences would be remembered on that device. However, your iPhone 6 will have always had iOS 8, and probably never asked to display push notifications because the API is different. Check out developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/… –  Asa Oct 8 '14 at 20:42

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243484/iphone-6-doesnt-receive-push-notification

Comment: @Tyegeh Also 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132664/push-notification-not-receiving-on-iphone?rq=1
Okay i finally got my Problem. The problem is not in code actually the problem is in Wrong DNS Value set in my iphone. Iphone automatically place ip of my router for DNS field. Now i give the DNS value of my service provider then it works fine. Now I am receiving Push messages As soon as i sent them.

---Might be helpful.

Comment: @Yogesh.Lolusare.Apple Wow, glad you have figured out your problem. For the notification preferences on iOS 8, I've tried reseting the device's contents and settings, install the app freshly again, and got the push notification pop up permission. But I'll check out your apple documentation reference for that. For the DNS value, I've never thought of that before but might worth checking out. Anyway, thank you so much for your help. I'll let you know if any of those you did works for me too. Cheers

Comment: Okay, to whoever is having the same problem as mine, it turned out that the mistake on my side was pretty silly. I didn't know I had to use the .pem file for Production Mode to be able to push notifications into the devices running with adhoc provisioning profile. So now, everything is solved. Thank you.